# Changing access rights of the specific folder for specifeid user

Tags: permissions, chmod, acl

what is the exact analog of the following two commands in linux

> # chmod -R +a "www-data allow
>   read,delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit"
>   /path/to/moodledata
>
> $ sudo chmod -R +a "`whoami` allow
>   read,delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit"
>   /path/to/moodledata

When I run these two commands I got

> chmod: invalid mode: `+a'

Here is the link where these two commands are written.
http://docs.moodle.org/25/en/Installing_Moodle
Go to the section "Create the (moodledata) data directory" on that document. 
are those commands  valid in Linux/Ubuntu?
My inverstigation says than +a mode for chmod is available for Mac OS. So  I want to ask  from experts whether linux/ubuntu have analogs of these two commands?

Comment: You do never want to `chmod 777` your moodledate folder, won't you?

Answer (score 0):

The chmod syntax allows to combine several attributes. For example

```
  chmod -R +w,+x,+r /path/that/is/not/your/moodledata
```

would be the equivalent of what you tried to achieve. It is always better, to combine this with a user option. The **-R** means that the changes are going to be done recursively.

```
  chmod -R g+w,u+w,o-w /path/that/is/not/your/moodledata
```

g=group, u=user, o=others. The attributes are **r** ead, **w** rite and e **x** ecute. By the way, `man chmod` can be your friend.

Comment: http://docs.moodle.org/25/en/Installing_Moodle

Comment: thanks for the answer. i had read the man. I changed my question the way that you can understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

for having the same (or near same) permissions in /moodledata first you should change the owner, the group and then set the permissions (it worked for me using moodle 2.7 from git on centos 6.6), given moodledata IS empty!

```
chown apache /path/to/moodledata

chgrp apache /path/to/moodledata

chmod 2777 /path/to/moodledata
```

executing 
sudo -u apache /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/moodle/admin/cli/install.php 
(beware! run SUDO as APACHE, not as ROOT!) notes:

*Data directories permission ==
type value, press Enter to use default value (2777)*

where 2777 is the default file permission.